# Removing the hash in my anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this piece of code to display the index value of my *cycle slides* at the end of the current URL.

```
 var index = 0, hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            index = /\d+/.exec(hash)[0];
            index = (parseInt(index) || 1) - 1; // slides are zero-based
        }
```

I would like to remove the '**#**' before the value. How should I modify this code?

Comment: FYI It's not called a hashtag, that's just twitters take on it's use.

Comment: @George Ok sorry, what's the correct term ?

Comment: [Number sign, pound sign or simply hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)

Comment: @George or "hash"... wikipedia: 'Outside of North America the symbol is called hash and the corresponding telephone key is called the "hash key"'

Comment: BTW any of you have an idea ;)

Comment: @clementr This looks like it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/v0gakv03/ what's the problem?

Comment: @jcuenod I want to get the my URL like this : http://url.com/3 not http://url.com/#3

Comment: hmm, I think I misunderstood, are you looking to pull the number off of the end of a url without a hash in it?

Comment: My bad I just make a big mistake I put the wrong part of my code. I actually what I was looking is `hash.match(/#(\d+)/)` but I need to integrate it to an other line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are trying to remove a hash from a string:

```
hash.replace(/#/, '')
```

```js
var hash = "url.com/#3"
document.getElementById("newUrl").innerHTML = hash.replace(/#/, '');
```

```html
<div id="newUrl"></div>
```

@SmokeyPHP below makes the point that I used regex to do this but you could equally give replace a string parameter: `hash.replace('#', '')`

Comment: Would just like to note that using regex for a single replacement is unnecessary, `.replace('#','')` does the same job without requiring regex parsing (though performance difference will be undetectable in this example). Just in case people don't realise that the first parameter can just be a string!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a match function to pull the hash off of the front and return the digits. For example

```
var hash = '#12'
var index = hash.match(/#(\d+)/)
if (hash.length) index = index[1] - 1
```

To integrate with your code

```
 var index = 0, hash = window.location.hash;
 if (hash) {
   index = hash.match(/#(\d+)/)
   index = (index.length ? index[1] - 1: 0); // slides are zero-based
 }
```

If you are looking to pull a number off of the end of a url without a hash in it try the following

```
window.location.href.match(/\/(\d+)(?:$|\?)/)
```

This ensures the digit(s) is/are the last item at the end of the url, with an optional ? for url vars